# NSAssert is enable after custom flutter engine

Tags: flutter, flutter-engine

I get a crash message，

NSInternalInconsistencyException
Invalid JSON message, decoding failed
CoreFoundation ___exceptionPreprocess

crash in FlutterCodecs.mm

NSAssert(encoding, @"Invalid JSON message, encoding failed");

I compiled the flutter engine myself, [Compiling-the-engine](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Compiling-the-engine)

How do I turn off NSAssert？